# Posting an update request to ElasticSearch without waiting for completion

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an ElasticSearch index that stores files, sometimes very large ones. Because the underlying Lucene engine is actually doing a complete replacement each time a document is updated, even if I am just modifying the value of one field, the entire document needs to be updated behind the scenes.

For large, multi-MB files this can take a fairly long time (several hundred ms). Since this is done as part of a web application this is not really acceptable. What I am doing right now is forking the process, so the update is called on a separate thread while the request finishes.

This works, but I'm not really happy with this as a long term solution, partially because it means that every time I create a new interface to the search engine I'll have to recode the forking logic. Also it means I basically can't know whether the request is successful or not, or if some kind of error occurred, without writing additional code to log successful or unsuccessful requests somewhere.

So I'm wondering if there is an unknown feature where you can post an UPDATE request to ElasticSearch, and have them return an acknowledgement without waiting for the update task to actually complete.

If you look at the [documentation for Snapshot and Restore](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) you'll see when you make a request you can add `wait_for_completion=true` in order to have the entire process run before receiving the result.

What I want is the reverse — the ability to add `?wait_for_completion=false` to a `POST` request.